# Do plugins for Kerbal Space Program work on unix?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have KSP installed on Ubuntu (via Steam) and I'm trying to install some plugins to make my rocket science easier.

I have successfully installed NovaPunch and it works (new parts appeared!). But MechJeb and Protractor do not work (I see no changes in UI).

So I tend to believe that there plugins that modify game UI do not support unix machines.
Or do I do something wrong? I have tried to unpack plugins both to separate directory (i.e. path is `...\protractor\Plugins`) and to game folder (so archive data is merged with original game data - I think that's correct way)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With very few exceptions, KSP mods are either parts only (and thus consist only of configuration files) or include plugins written in C# (which work on both Linux and Windows). MechJeb and Protractor specifically I can confidently say work on Linux because I'm using both right now.

All mods - parts or plugins - should be installed to the GameData directory. For example, if KSP were installed in `~/Games/KSP`, with MechJeb installed you should have a directory structure that looks something like this:

```
~/Games/KSP/
  ...other KSP directories...
  GameData/
    Squad/
      ...base game files...
    MechJeb2/
      Parts/
        ...MJ part configurations...
      Plugins/
        ...MJ plugin DLL and PluginData files...
```

Bear in mind that with MechJeb you need to install a MechJeb part on your rocket to see any UI changes. Furthermore, if you're playing in career mode, you'll need to unlock it in the tech tree before it appears.

Comment: Ahh looks like I had installed them improperly! I will try this way today.

Comment: I have moved plugin folder to GameData and it works! thank you!
for the reference by default GameData path is ~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Kerbal Space Program/GameData

Comment: That's only if you installed it through Steam, which not everyone does, so I decided to go with a short, generic path instead. Glad you got it working. :)

Comment: @ToxicFrog Hey. Thanks for the answer! Perhaps to make it most generic, show it as "'KPSINSTALLDIR/GameData/...' (where KSPINSTALLDIR is '~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Kerbal Space Program' on Steam, or '~' otherwise)"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on [how the plugin was developed](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Plugins).  Unfortunately, it's basically impossible to tell which IDE was used to compile the DLL.  As far as I know, parts only mods should work regardless of the platform (although [the wiki](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Part_Modelling_Guidelines) is somewhat vague).

As for where to put mods, each mod keeps all of its data in a single parent folder that's typically named after the mod.  In this folder there will be at least a "Plugins" and/or "Parts" folder, with the possibility of a source folder as well.  Note that some mods use plugins developed by others, such as the B9 pack, which uses the Firespitter plugin, among others.  These plugins will generally be contained in their own parent folder to prevent loading two or more DLLs with the same name.  All of these parent folders should be placed in the "GameData" folder.

Comment: IDEs don't compile things. Compilers do. That's what counts.